# SMD LED lifetime

Tags: led, circuit-design

Given an SMD LED with a maximum rated continuous current of 30 mA and a maximum power of 75 mW. I know it is good practice to run the LED at about half of the rated current.

What exactly would happen if, say, the LED is used to its maximum of 30-31 mA at room temperature for long periods of time? Would the LED just burn, or dim? Of course the LED's lifetime would be affected, but would it be more than half of its lifetime, or would the LED just work for a few days and then burn out?

Comment: Which LED? Show the datasheet, edit the link into your question.

Comment: Not all datasheets offer specs for this kind of thing. My understanding is that the spec'ed lifetime is *at* the rated current. When we used 2xAAA + button + *no resistor* on simple diy magic wands, they did not die, but got very dim pretty fast, fast enough for people to notice during the event (few minutes of "on" time total?). Poor tortured LEDs. So it's probably (my guess) not instant (unless you downright blast them), but a function of how much you torture those things.

Comment: Hard to tell. Some burn their phosphor layer and subsequently dim, some fail their bonding and simply go out.

Comment: It's old, now. And it does NOT cover SMD LEDs. But perhaps the most solid book on the topic is from Hewlett-Packard and is called, "*Optoelectronics: Fiber-Optics Applications Manual*", 2nd edition, circa 1980. If you can find a copy, I'd highly recommend getting it as a reference text. It covers more of the failure mechanisms then known than anything else I've seen since then. So, if nothing else, it will inspire your imagination in good directions, I believe. Get yourself a copy, if you can.

Comment: Also note that the chip temp will be quite different from room temp at full power. How you heatsink it is going to significantly affect what happens.

Comment: This is impossible to answer. **How** something will fail depends on many factors. Also, it might not fail but simpy wear out. What do you then consider a fail, when the emitted light is 50% of its original value or 10%? Even if you use an LED at 1/2 of its rated current, it can still fail but the chance of that happening is **much less** than when using it at its full rated current. Statistics also play a role. So if possible, create margins like by using the LED at 1/2 of its rated current. If you need more light or a higher current, use **two** LEDs.

Comment: This is a well researched topic, I would recommend some googling for "led lifetime" over posting here. You'll find some extensive exploration of the various factors.

Comment: Here is one example that looks at your specific question about derating the current: https://docs.rs-online.com/4592/0900766b80e289cf.pdf

Comment: I don't think this question needs more clarity or details. LED lifetime can absolutely be discussed and understood independently of a specific part number.

Comment: As a general rule the current (within specs) will not affect the lifetime if the LED stays cool. But if you let it get hot, its lifetime will drop quite fast and that's where reducing the current can help.

Comment: As to what happens, and short of the LED violently burning out, it's a combination of the chip itself getting dimmer over time and the optics getting less transparent as they bake.

Comment: One last link: https://lamphq.com/led-degradation/